# Should I delete local pointers in functions? (C++)

Tags: c++, pointers

A question:

Should I delete pointers which are fetched in functions (not created, just fetched)? Example:

```c
#include <SomeObject>

#define SAFE_DELETE(p) { if (p) { delete (p); (p) = NULL; } }

class DraftObject
{
public:

    DraftObject() : _x(0) {}
    ~DraftObject(){}

    int CalculateSomething()
    {
        AnotherObject* aObj = SomeObject::getInstance()->getAObjPointer();

        /* Do some calculations and etc... */
        _x += aObj->GetSomeIntValue();

        SAFE_DELETE(aObj) // <-- Would you recomend this here?

        return _x;
    }

protected:
    int _x;
};
```

The aObj would be re-used in other cases as well in the SomeObject instance. I could go on and always call `SomeObject::getInstance()->getAObjPointer()` for everything I need it for, but `SomeObject::getInstance()->getAObjPointer()->GetSomeIntValue()` is not as readable as `aObj->GetSomeIntValue()` in my personal opinion.
I know that I would not need to worry if I used something from boost (shared_ptr, weak_ptr or even auto_ptr), but I am more curious about the way this works. Will not deleting the pointer create a memory leak situation or will the deletion of the pointer delete it from the memory so that it will be gone in other scopes (the instance object as well as anywhere else it might be used) ?

Any thoughts?

Cheers.

Comment: `delete` what you `new`.

Comment: Note that `delete 0;` is a no-op.

Comment: If `getAObjPointer` just returns a reference, you are not supposed to delete it. If there is any new operation at the called location, you have to delete it. Or else you have references dangling around.

Comment: @Mahesh if it returned a reference, the code wouldn't compile. You can't assign a reference to a pointer (unless it's a pointer reference).

Comment: Wow, I didn't even have time to blink when my question was answered. Thank you all. Makes sense. I suspected such a thing, but wasn't sure. Cheers all.

Comment: @Mahesh `int& foo()` returns a reference, `int* foo()` returns a pointer.

Comment: If you have control over the interface, then you should change the return type so that it is more descriptive.  Return `std::auto_ptr<AnotherObject>` (or `std::unique_ptr<AnotherObject>`) if `getAObjPointer()` transfers ownership of the allocated object to its caller, otherwise return a reference type (`AnotherObject &`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends.

If `SomeObject::getInstance()->getAObjPointer();` returns a different object each call, probably yes. Otherwise, no. **This should be documented**.

Also, your "safe delete":

```
#define SAFE_DELETE(p) { if (p) { delete (p); (p) = NULL; } }
```

is **utterly useless**. And ugly. If I saw this in code, I'd go and make fun of the programmer who wrote it. If `p` is `NULL`, the delete is safe.

Comment: I agree.  The SAFE_DELETE stuff is totally useless.

Comment: I don't like the "make fun" part.

Comment: @NisonMaël I take it you just wrote that :P

Comment: The macro isn't totally worthless, it is setting `p` to `NULL`, which a simple `delete` doesn't do by itself. The macro could be simplified to `#define SAFE_DELETE(p) {delete p; p = NULL;}`

Comment: @LuchianGrigore would you say that `#define SAFE_DELETE(p) { delete (p); (p) = NULL; }` would be a lot better in this case?

EDIT: @Prætorian we literally wrote this down at the same time. Cheers

Comment: @karmalis I'm saying you should't use a macro, just use delete.

Comment: @Prætorian I didn't say a simple delete does that. But you don't need a macro to set a pointer to null. What's wrong with good old-fashioned assignment? `SAFE_DELETE` gives a sense of false security. If it just deletes and sets the pointer to null, wouldn't `DELETE_AND_SET_TO_NULL` be a more appropriate name?

Comment: I always thought that safe deleting was good coding practice. Especially when checking the pointer itself. On some occasions when you try to delete a null pointer, you might get access violation. On small projects, you might notice that, but on larger ones, you might miss it.

Comment: @karmalis "On some occasions when you try to delete a null pointer, you might get access violation." you're wrong. You can always delete a null pointer safely.

Comment: I never said the macro was named appropriately or that it was better than explicitly deleting and then setting the pointer to `nullptr`; in fact, I prefer the latter. But you called it ***utterly useless***, and so I was just pointing out that it does have its use, aesthetics aside.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore I am not the one who said that: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6227113.aspx "Using delete on a pointer to an object not allocated with new gives unpredictable results"

Comment: @karmalis Yes, `delete`ing an object that has not been allocated using `new` is undefined behavior. But your macro does not prevent that in any way. I can still write `Foo f; SAFE_DELETE(&f);` and the program would most likely crash (if you're lucky). What Luchian's trying to say is that it is OK to `delete` a NULL pointer. `void *p = NULL; delete p;` is perfectly valid and exhibits defined behavior, it does nothing (no-op).

Comment: @karmalis msdn is not the governing body for C++, although a pointer allocated with new can't be null. new doesn't ever return null. If you read the standard you will see that deleting a null pointer is valid and well-defined.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore I agree completely and understand what you mean. What I mean is that using this particular function will never fail you on any of the compilers. This always comes into account when working on cross-platform projects.

Comment: @karmalis I didn't say it would fail, just that it's useless. Scattering around `4+5;` will also work. Declaring unused variables will compile as well. It's just useless. If deleting a NULL pointer is ok, **why** would you check for null beforehand?

Comment: @Prætorian I wouldn't use SAFE_DELETE(&f) personally. SAFE_DELETE is only meant for pointers in all of my cases.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore this would be to avoid programming mistakes. I.E. avoid deleting the same pointer twice. But that's not the only one example.

Comment: @karmalis it doesn't solve anything. It gives a false sense of safety, when in fact it's not safe. How does it prevent you from deleting the same pointer twice. Checking or not checking for null **changes absolutely nothing**.

Comment: @Prætorian I didn't necesarrily had a problem with the macro, but with the null-check.

Comment: There is a single useful usage of setting a pointer to NULL (or nullptr ;) after deleting it : if it gets dereferenced, the program will always crash. It's sometimes a good thing to early spot errors.

Comment: @NisonMaël I agree, but as I stated before, I don't have a problem with that. I have a problem with checking for null before.

Comment: @NisonMaël also, setting or not setting to null, after the delete, if you use the pointer it's undefined behavior. Could crash even if you don't set it to null, or it might work if you do. Undefined.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore Indeed. However, if you use a pointer after deleting it, it will probably not crash until the next allocations, because it's memory will still be here, and because the implementors doesn't lower the brk.
Either case, valgrind should still do some BWARGHH if an invalid pointer is used :)

Comment: And actually I'm partially wrong; even with a nullptr, non-virtual member functions will not crash when called, until they try to dereference 'this'.

Answer (score 0):

No, do not use `delete` because that will deallocate the memory for the object and you will not be able to use it later.

Comment: How do you know the method doesn't return a new object every call? If it does, that's a memory leak.

Comment: I think that's what the OP meant when he said "The aObj would be re-used in other cases as well in the SomeObject instance."  It's a really unclear question though.

Answer (score 0):

It should be documented in the API.

Some libraries are returning pointers which SHOULD NOT be deleted by the users, because they are also kept in internal data structures. Others are creating pointers which should be deleted by the user.

Assuming that you have actually wrote yourself this class and function, you probably want to delete the pointer at the end of the function if you don't use use this instance anywhere else (including in internals functions).

Comment: In my particular case the object is created on the instance and re-used multiple times, not de-allocated at the end of the DraftObject. Not deleting it after the use is the answer I was looking for. Thanks.